# How to shuffle big volumes of data?

Tags: shuffle, random-access, leveldb

I have to train an image classifier on an image dataset. There are about a 1 000 000 images. Each image is about 100 Kb, so in total it is 100 Gb of data.

I have to feed the trainer with all dataset about 100 times (100 epochs).
Each epoch should be given by portions (about 1000 images in each) to provide stochastic gradient descent. To reduce overtraining, the portions should be the pieces of a random split of my dataset. Each epoch I should re-split it once again.

I have 16 Gb of memory. It is too little to store all data. Ergo, I have to somehow store it on disk.

Also, I know, that random-location disk read is really slow, even if I use `leveldb` or something like that. So, I have to re-dump the data in right shuffled order.

How can it be done best?

Comment: Disk read location becomes irrelevant if you have access to an SSD.

Comment: AFAIK, sequentional reading will still be much faster than reading from random small files. Some DBs also can perform asynchronous prefetching of next-laying data.

Comment: As long as your files are reasonably large (read: 64 kB and up), which your 100 kB files are, an SSD will suffer very little speed loss due to random sectors, especially when compared to a regular hard drive. [See a sample reading](http://goo.gl/8kTu6L). Additionally you will receive reasonably uniform (and faster) read speeds on an SSD, for example compare [a HDD read graph](http://goo.gl/W27WTs) and [an SSD read graph](http://goo.gl/Pjm4Ry). While these are specific samples, the trend is the same for all drives. But all this is just technicality, steering away from the actual question.

Comment: In this case leveldb is overkill. It depends on the rest of the program. Don't forget the "ordered" in ordered key-value store.